# Need a good jQuery image manipulation plugin

Tags: jquery, asp.net, image-processing

I am trying to find a good jQuery plugin for doing image manipulation. Specifically, I would like the user to be able to upload an image, crop it and resize it, then do some basic stuff like adjust the brightness and/or contrast, and maybe some other basic stuff, like color or gamma adjustments.

Is there a good jQuery recommendation for a plugin that does these things? My web server is powered by ASP.NET, so an ASP.NET friendly jquery plugin would be perfect. Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is not free, but Telerik has an [Image Editor 
for ASP.NET AJAX](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/imageeditor.aspx). This has a client-side API that allows for JavaScript/jQuery interaction with the image editor.